# How count number of lines in linux excluding headers?

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I have to count the number of replicasets running in a system.

`kubectl get replicasets | wc -l`

It give output `2` as it counts the header as well.

```
NAME              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
new-replica-set   4         4         0       20s
```

How to print the count excluding the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `no-headers`

`kubectl get replicasets --no-headers | wc -l`

if you want to count `rs` from all namespaces just add `-A` before `--no-headers`

`kubectl get replicasets -A --no-headers | wc -l`

Comment: Yes, will do it after 2mins as there is a time limit for accepting answers.